# Debugging step buttons disabled in Eclipse Oxygen

Tags: eclipse, debugging, eclipse-oxygen

I have upgraded Eclipse to Oxygen, with Scala and Python added. I noticed that when programming in Java, the step commands of the debugger remain disabled.
I can run the debugger, and it will run until it hits a breakpoint, but then i cannot step in or over. I can only stop the (local) VM.

Any thoughts?

Comment: In the _Debug_ view, make sure you have selected a thread that is paused by a breakpoint, not a running thread (the step commands refer to the selected thread).

Comment: I do that already. It doesn't work.

Comment: Could you please add a screenshot of the _Debugging_ perspective to your question?

Comment: https://imgur.com/aNuG2ux

Comment: How did you upgrade Eclipse?

Comment: Can you check Debugger timeout(ms) value. The field is available Preferences---> Debug---> Communication.

Comment: Same problem with Eclipse Oxygen 4.7.1a, trying to debug an application running in JDK 7. The problem disappears when debugging the application with JDK 8.

Comment: The application I am debugging has 100+ threads.  Is there a reason Eclipse could not have automatically selected the thread where the breakpoint was hit?  I had to hunt for it and select it.

Answer (score 2):

In my case increasing the "debug timeout" value resolved the problem.  Thanks to @Shahbaz Ahmad comment.

Preferences >> Debug >> Connection Timeout

Answer (score 0):

If you have all code in main function then put a breakpoint at main function as well.
And if you have multiple functions,  breakpoint  on methods as well ( if you have breakpoint inside that method).

Basically, put a breakpoint on the function in which you have added breakpoints.